# How to use "conda update -n base conda" properly

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have two very simple questions regarding updating conda. I.e. when updating one of my environments with
`conda update --all`, I get a warning

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: xyz1
  latest version: xyz2

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda
```

My setup comprises a base environment and two actual work environments, say, (env1) and (env2). The latter two environments are kept up to date with `conda update --all`, issued within each of those environments. The base environment was only generated in the installation process of Anaconda.

*Question 1*: Should one run `conda update -n base conda` on the command line of the OS (linux) **prior** to activating any environment? Or should one activate a particular environment? Or is the environment out of which this command is issued irrelevant?

*Question 2*: After running `conda update -n base conda` from out of whatever environment, as determined by the answer to question 1, would a subsequent `conda update --all` issued within one of my two work environments (env1,2) install or update any additional stuff, only as a consequence of the previous `conda update -n base conda`?

(PS.: I find many questions on stackoverflow regarding `conda update conda`, but they don't seem to cover this one.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q1:
`-n` explicitly specifies environment - this command will run in any environment and even if you have no environment active.

Q2:
In all but very few cases updating conda will not affect the packages ought to be installed in other environments. conda plays the role as a package manager. The packages are pulled from an index that is independent of conda's version.

Comment: The answer to Q1 worked, even though it might be of help for others who follow this, that after issuing `conda update -n base conda` and with no environment active, it was not only conda which got updated, but a whole bunch of other packages too - I guess in the base environment.

Answer (score 35):

If you are very behind on conda version like I was, I found that it will not update no matter what.  In this case, try:

`conda install -n base -c defaults conda=23.3.1`

(**NOTE:** `install` rather than update)  Just fill in whatever version it is asking you to update to.

**EDIT:**
following the comment by @merv, include `'conda>=VERSION'` included quotes to make sure you update to any version past the one specified (`ENV` being the environment you want to upgrade, e.g. `base`, and `VERSION` being the version you want to install to):

`conda install -n ENV 'conda>=VERSION'`

Comment: Better: define as a lower bound, that way it won’t block next time when doing update. `'conda>=23.3.1'` (be sure to use the quotes)

Answer (score 6):

you deal with conda like any other package manager you update it in base environment by `conda update -n base conda`

```
conda update --all
```

is meant to update all packages in the activated environment
[check this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/update-version/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything, in the end what worked was using this to update miniconda https://docs.conda.io/projects/miniconda/en/latest/