# conda warns me I should update conda, but the update keeps failing

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

### The issue

I have an Anaconda distribution installed on a Windows PC about 18 months ago. I updated the whole package with conda update --all but conda remains stuck at version 4.12.0
When using conda, I often get the message that

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: xyz1
  latest version: xyz2

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda
```

### What I have tried

`conda update conda` tells me that all requested packages are already installed

`conda update -n base conda` tells me all requested packages are already installed

`conda install conda=23.3.1` doesn't work: it fails with the current repodata, it tries the next (what does this mean - I only have 'default' as channel in my .condarc file) but after 2 hours it is still stuck at "solving environment"

### What I have researched

I have found many posts on how to use conda in general, e.g. [How to use "conda update -n base conda" properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365296/how-to-use-conda-update-n-base-conda-properly) but they are not about what would prevent you from updating conda itself

### My interpretation

Maybe there is some package which is incompatible with conda > 4.12.0 ? Is there a way to find out which package it is? Or maybe it is just some bug in conda?

Comment: I also had same problem with you. Now every time running geopandas, kernel keeps dying when updating or reinstalling geopandas the message conda update -n base conda is pop up again and again. @Pythonista anonymous. do you found solution by now? please share here

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it was solved with the following command:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda --repodata-fn=repodata.json
```

I hope I have helped you

Comment: I really hope this will help me. Will try soon. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By doing this, do you face any problem with other scripts or applications? coz im trying to figure out why json came into this problem

Comment: @Azam Running it on Ubuntu didn't cause any issues for me.

Comment: Thanks. I have migrated to python 3.8 and the problem resolved. the best thing is I started to fall in love with mamba. it faster installing than in regular conda

Comment: @Azam Very good, I had not heard of this item, thank you, I will definitely give it a try.

Comment: Can you explain why this works? What does it do?