# How do I update to new version of conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

My conda version is 4.x

while new version is 23.x

I am trying to run the command it asks me to run to update, but that doesn't seem to update it.

I installed miniconda in base while doing initial installation

```
==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.11.0
  latest version: 23.5.0

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

I have tried the above and all I get is:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
# All requested packages already installed.
```

But it still shows version as 4.x

Comment: See also post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70365296/how-to-use-conda-update-n-base-conda-properly

Answer (score 2):

Try updating conda with this command:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda --repodata-fn=repodata.json
```

hope it works.
And there is a brief discussion on GitHub. [conda update conda does not update conda](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/12519#issuecomment-1483106227)

Answer (score 0):

Removing a bunch of packages from the base environment (the huge number of packages in Anaconda base environment create dependency conflicts nightmares) worked for me.

Try running the following in your base (root) environment:

**conda remove statsmodels spyder sphinx scipy scikit-learn pytest numba numexpr mkl lxml flask debugpy dask cloudpickle bokeh beautifulsoup4**

Then after everything has been removed successfully, run:
**conda update –all**

And with any luck, conda should be updated to the latest version. I recommend you create separate virtual environments if you want to use any of those packages you removed to avoid dependency issues.